# Merging two convex hulls

Tags: java, algorithm, convex-hull

I'm currently writing a divide and conquer version of the Convex Hull algorithm and it's very close to working but am having trouble merging two convex hulls (to form the overall convex hull).

I'm merging by:

- Computing Upper & Lower Hulls for each Input Hull, A and B
- Finding the combined upper hull by ensuring right turns
- Finding the combined lower hull by ensuring left turns
- Computing the union of the 2 combined hulls

I'm not 100% sure if this is the right way to do it - any guidance or pseudocode for finding combined upper/lower hulls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out; it'll give you very clever approaches to convex hull manipulation

https://web.archive.org/web/20120617005317/http://moais.imag.fr/membres/denis.trystram/SupportsDeCours/convexHull.pdf

Comment: I completely understand the approach, but it's the process of finding upper & lower tangents I'm struggling with?

Comment: URL dead: https://web.archive.org/web/20120617005317/http://moais.imag.fr/membres/denis.trystram/SupportsDeCours/convexHull.pdf

Comment: Also this should be in arbitrary dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

While this is using the XNA library, you can definitely port this to Java:

```
public static class PolygonUnion
{
        public static bool PolyUnion(Vector2[] polya, Vector2[] polyb, out Vector2[] union, out Vector2[] intersection)
        {
            if (!Intersects(polya, polyb))
            {
                union = polya;
                intersection = polyb;
                return false;
            }

            LList a = new LList(polya), b = new LList(polyb);
            List<Intersection> intersections = new List<Intersection>();

            Vector2 vert;
            VNode aNode = a.First, bNode = b.First;
            //Find intersection points between the polygons
            do
            {
                do
                {
                    if (EdgeIntersects(aNode.Value, (aNode.Next == null) ? a.First.Value : aNode.Next.Value, bNode.Value,
(bNode.Next == null) ? b.First.Value : bNode.Next.Value, out vert))
                    {
                        //An intersection point has been found!
                        intersections.Add(new Intersection(vert, aNode, bNode, (aNode.Next == null) ? a.First : aNode.Next,
(bNode.Next == null) ? b.First : bNode.Next));
                    }
                    bNode = bNode.Next;
                }
                while (bNode != null);
                bNode = b.First;
                aNode = aNode.Next;
            }
            while (aNode != null);
            //Perform surgery on these intersections
            Intersection i;
            for (int j = 0; j < intersections.Count; j++)
            {
                i = intersections[j];
                i.aIn.Next = new VNode(i.Position, i.bOut, i.aIn);
                i.bOut.Prev = i.aIn.Next;

                i.bIn.Next = new VNode(i.Position, i.aOut, i.bIn);
                i.aOut.Prev = i.bIn.Next;
            }
            //Decompose and simplify polygons into arrays
            union = a.ToArray();
            intersection = b.ToArray();

            //Find exterior polygon
            if (union.Length < intersection.Length)
            {
                //Polygons need swapping!
                Vector2[] u = union;
                union = intersection;
                intersection = u;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private class Intersection
        {
            public Intersection(Vector2 position, VNode aIn, VNode bIn, VNode aOut, VNode bOut)
            {
                this.aIn = aIn;
                this.bIn = bIn;
                this.aOut = aOut;
                this.bOut = bOut;
                this.Position = position;
            }

            public VNode aIn, bIn, aOut, bOut;
            public Vector2 Position;
        }

        private class LList
        {
            public LList(Vector2[] poly)
            {
                First = new VNode(poly[0], null, null);

                current = First;
                for (int i = 1; i < poly.Length; i++)
                {
                    Add(current, poly[i]);
                    current = current.Next;
                }
                current = First;
            }

            private void Add(VNode prev, Vector2 pos)
            {
                prev.Next = new VNode(pos, null, prev);
            }

            public VNode First;
            private VNode current;

            public Vector2[] ToArray()
            {
                List<Vector2> ret = new List<Vector2>();
                current = First;
                int timeout = 1000;
                bool starting = true;

                while (current != null)
                {
                    if (current.Prev != null && current.Value == current.Prev.Value)
                    {
                        current = current.Next;
                        if (current.Value == current.Next.Value && current.Value == current.Prev.Value) break;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (!starting && current.Value == First.Value) break;
                    starting = false;

                    ret.Add(current.Value);
                    current = current.Next;

                    timeout--;
                    if (timeout <= 0) break;
                }
                return Simplify(ret.ToArray());
            }
        }

        private class VNode
        {
            public VNode(Vector2 value, VNode next, VNode prev)
            {
                Value = value;
                Next = next;
                Prev = prev;
            }

            public VNode Next;
            public VNode Prev;
            public Vector2 Value;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        private static Vector2[] Simplify(Vector2[] poly)
        {
            const float tolerance = 25f;//5 pixels tolerance. (5^2 to save sqrt)
            if (poly.Length == 0) return poly;

            List<Vector2> ret = new List<Vector2>(1);
            ret.Add(poly[0]);
            float dist;

            for (int i = 1; i < poly.Length; i++)
            {
                dist = (poly[ret.Count - 1] - poly[i]).LengthSquared();
                if (dist < tolerance) continue;
                if (ret.Contains(poly[i])) continue;

                ret.Add(poly[i]);
            }
            return ret.ToArray();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the line segments intersect.
        /// </summary>
        private static bool EdgeIntersects(Vector2 x, Vector2 y, Vector2 a, Vector2 b, out Vector2 i)
        {
            i = Vector2.Zero;
            float dx, dy, da, db, t, s;

            dx = y.X - x.X;
            dy = y.Y - x.Y;
            da = b.X - a.X;
            db = b.Y - a.Y;
            if ((da * dy - db * dx) == 0) return false;

            s = (dx * (a.Y - x.Y) + dy * (x.X - a.X)) / (da * dy - db * dx);
            t = (da * (x.Y - a.Y) + db * (a.X - x.X)) / (db * dx - da * dy);
            i = new Vector2(x.X + t * dx, x.Y + t * dy);
            return (bool)(s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1);
        }

        #region Intersection Test
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if two polygons intersect.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool Intersects(Vector2[] aPoints, Vector2[] bPoints)
        {
            Vector2 edge, axis;
            float minA, maxA, minB, maxB, overlap;
            //Loop through all edges until a seperating axis is found
            for (int x = 0; x < aPoints.Length + bPoints.Length; x++)
            {
                //Calculate the current edge
                if (x < aPoints.Length) edge = aPoints[(x == aPoints.Length - 1 ? 0 : x + 1)] - aPoints[x];
                else
                {
                    x -= aPoints.Length;
                    edge = bPoints[(x == bPoints.Length - 1 ? 0 : x + 1)] - bPoints[x];
                    x += aPoints.Length;
                }
                //Find the axis perpendicular to current edge
                axis = new Vector2(-edge.Y, edge.X);
                axis.Normalize();
                //Project the two shapes onto this axis
                //Project this
                ProjectPoly(aPoints, axis, out maxA, out minA);
                ProjectPoly(bPoints, axis, out maxB, out minB);
                //Find the overlap between them
                if (minA < minB) overlap = minB - maxA;
                else overlap = minA - maxB;
                //If the overlap is negative then they are overlapping and the smallest
                //overlap must be found to find the minumum translation.
                //If it is bigger than 0 then they won't overlap at all.
                if (overlap < 0) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Projects a polygon onto the axis, giving the maximum and minimum positions.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="points">Points that are in world space with origin at the centre</param>
        private static void ProjectPoly(Vector2[] points, Vector2 axis, out float max, out float min)
        {
            //Projecting a point onto an axis uses a dot product.
            float dotProduct = Vector2.Dot(axis, points[0]);
            min = dotProduct;
            max = dotProduct;
            //Now project the rest of the polygon...
            for (int i = 1; i < points.Length; i++)
            {
                dotProduct = Vector2.Dot(axis, points[i]);
                if (dotProduct < min) min = dotProduct;
                else if (dotProduct > max) max = dotProduct;
            }
        }
        #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you mean by lower and upper and it would be good to specify if it is 2D or 3D.

For a 2D convex hull. I have made an algorithm, which, according to my tests is the fastest (at least twice as fast as Chan) and both are in O(n log h).

But what also differenciate mine, is that is support "online" feeding. I mean that you can add one point at a time dynamically (no remove supported yet). Everything stay in O (log h) per point which is actually the fastest you can get. I think, it is also the only one that is online and being in that performance range.

The article about the convex hull is : [Fast and improved 2D Convex Hull algorithm and its implementation in O(n log h)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1210225/Fast-and-improved-D-Convex-Hull-algorithm-and-its). But the "online" portion is not yet documented. I just finalize it today (2018-01-25). But all the code is accessible at [GitHub](https://github.com/EricOuellet2/ConvexHull).

For simplicity you can only use the online portion to merge anything dynamically with this code (you can add convex hull point or any point):

```
OuelletConvexHullAvl2Online.ConvexHullOnline convexHullOnline = new OuelletConvexHullAvl2Online.ConvexHullOnline();
                    foreach (Point pt in points)
                    {
                        convexHullOnline.DynamicallyAddAnotherPointToConvexHullIfAppropriate(pt);
                    }

                    return convexHullOnline.GetResultsAsArrayOfPoint();
```